# Disable apache.http.wire DEBUG logs

Tags: java, logging, travis-ci, jena, dbpedia

I'm using Travis CI with my github repo(java project). One of my tests gets data from Dbpedia using SPARQL and Jena. It causes many records i get to be printed in the log into Travis output and thus Travis fails.

A log example for instance:

```
14:52:58.756 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "    {   
"pname": { "type": "literal", "xml:lang": "en", "value": "Yuen Poovarawan"
 }[0x9], "photo": { "type": "uri", "value": "http://commons.wikimedia.org 
 /wiki/Special:FilePath/Yuen_Poovarawan.jpg?width=300" }[0x9], "birth": { 
"type": "uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Thailand" }[0x9], 
"bDate": { "type": "typed-literal", "datatype": "http://www.w3.org
/2001/XMLSchema#date",   "value": "1950-11-05" }[0x9], "bExp": { "type": 
"uri", "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Thailand" }},[\n]"
```

All of these logs start with `[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire`. How can i disable them so Travis passes?
I've found [how to disable it using scala/logback.xml](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java/issues/77) but the log.xml is defined for console. I need help to use it right, can you please help/guide me?

Comment: This isn't a Jena issue. Somehow debug level logging has been switched on for at least org.apache.http.wire (which isn't part of Jena). Ideally, set your your logging so as not to include DEBUG on "org.apache.http". org.apache.http.wire does not appear to be part of the http-components, http-client use by the current release of Jena.

Answer (score 4):

Create a logback.xml with below contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
</configuration>
```

Then put this logback.xml in your java source dir so it will be included in jar file. Otherwise create a jar from logback.xml and put this jar to your lib where you fetch all your jars.

A simple way to create logback.jar from logback.xml is using ant.
Create build.xml with below code:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<project name="test" default="compile" basedir=".">
<target name = "build-jar">
   <jar destfile = "op/logback.jar"
      basedir = "in">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name = "Main-Class" value = "com.tutorialspoint.util.FaxUtil"/>
      </manifest>
   </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Create a directory structure like:

|-- build.xml

|-- in --> logback.xml

|-- op --> logback.jar //This will be generated after execution of ant command

Now compile using ant build-jar
You will have logback.jar. Put this jar with all other jars and it will remove org.apache.http.wire DEBUG log